# Significance of the starting scene in the movie Maurice

Tags: plot-explanation, maurice

In the starting scene of  *[Maurice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093512/)* (1987) we see Maurice receive some advice on relationships and physical changes he will be experiencing in future.

Is there any significance of this starting scene because apparently it seems to have nothing to do with the rest of the movie.